# How to change page title dynamicly without refresh site

Tags: asp.net

i wanna have a Faceook-Feature in my website: Everytime a user gets a Private Message, the title should be change in something like "[1 PM] TITLE",

How to do that?

I know its easy to change the page-title, the question is how to run a database query every 10 seconds (or is that to often?) and change the title - Without an user interaction (ajax?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jquery setInterval to make a AJAX request after a certain interval to get data from the db.

```
$(function(){
    setInterval(function() {

    $.ajax({
    url: "page.html",
    success: {
    document.title ='new title';
    },
    error: function(){
    //error occurred
    }
    });
    }, 2000);
});
```

And on AJAX success you can change the page title.

Comment: Thank you, can you explain a bit more? Where to write this setInterval-function and how to call a function in BackAnd there?

Comment: Thank you, last question: Is this function started on PageLoad?
How to call a C#-Function from Backend?

Comment: @Kovu - no problem, happy to help you. Check out these links http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/ and this http://deebujacob.blogspot.in/2012/01/aspnet-ajax-web-method-call-using.html it expains how you can make an ajax call to a server side method in c#. And yes, $(function() will be called at page load, you can find more about it over here http://api.jquery.com/ready/